# Compare geolocations to determine duplicates in Ruby

Tags: ruby, geolocation, compare

I'm currently building a small script that holds a nested array of venues from foursquare. As foursquare is crowdsourced there are many times duplicated venues (two or more venues which are actually the same place). I'm trying to determine if there's a GEM or a service in Ruby I can use to compare the geolocations between them and determine wherever they're probably duplicate venues.

The challenge here is that both lat and long have to be used in order to detect proximity.

For example I have array [[9.921092271, -84.02182584], [9.940208327, 84.184437]  ] and I want to see if the're very close (by a said range, let's say 200 feet). This could be done easily by doing some math but's not good if there are a lot of geolocations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something is going to have to do the math in order to determine proximity. Why wouldn't it? Do you not know how to do the math, or not know how to loop over all the data sets?

Comment: I know how to do the math @theTinMan but I would like to determine if there's a simpler (or if someone had taken the time do come up with a gem) way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`geocoder` gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) has some convenience methods that are relevant here.

You could set it up for your example like:

```
require 'geocoder'

def close?(lat_longs, distance_in_feet)  
  distance_in_miles = distance_in_feet.to_f / 5280.to_f

  lat_longs.combination(2).each do |lat_long|
    if Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(*lat_long) > distance_in_miles
      return false
    end
  end
  true
end

close?([[9.921092271, -84.02182584], [9.940208327, 84.184437]], 200)
# false
```

Comment: Thanks for Geocoder, it's quite what I was looking for. However this solutions works when they're 2 geolocations. I'm currently investigating to compare between elements on an array so this solution can be scalable

Comment: I've updated my answer to work with an array of any length. I don't know of any Geocoder method that will do exactly what you are asking directly, but it has a lot of great stuff for mixing in with ActiveRecord, etc. If you need more functionality than this method provides, check out the Geocoder documentation.

Comment: Thanks @kardeiz your insight was quite helpfull